# Basic Python on Geany error

Tags: python, geany

When running this simple python program on Geany (I am just learning how to program for the first time):

```
name = input(What is your name?: ")
age = int(How old are you?: "))
year = str((2017 - age) + 100
print(name + "will be 100 years old in the year " + year)
```

I get this error:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program, or batch file.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Comment: @varfirstName No worries, I knew someone would be able to help that had more time to look at the provided code so it was just a comment with a link just in case without putting much thought in it as well. Good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't run because you were missing multiple quotes, parentheses, and a method.

My file is as such:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
age = input("How old are you?: ")
year = str((2017 - age) + 100)
print(name + "will be 100 years old in the year " + year)
```

Also, your filename doesn't have any extension so Geany has no clue that it's a Python file. So it just tries to run it and fails because it has no proper command to run the file.

If you resave the file with a .py extension, it specifies to Geany that it needs to run the file using the Python command.

Comment: Yes, that's when it fails. I copy pasted your code into geany

Comment: What did you save the file as?

Comment: 100 years old program (in my documents folder)

Comment: does it have an extension? like .exe or .html or .py or anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't have an extension. Sorry, had to change my view settings to see

Comment: Re-save it with a .py extension

Comment: Ok, I think that helped, but I modified my path earlier, because I thought that was the problem. Now it says it does not recognize python as an external ect. command. Thanks. I'll try to fix the path and come back later.

Comment: Instead of fixing the path (while I do recommend that), you can just press Alt+B, and then S after letting go of alt, to access the build commands. From there, replace "python" with "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe"

Comment: or you can replace "%f" with "%p\%f" and then put C:\Program Files\Python36 in the spot for working directory

Comment: Btw, I'm running python 27. Any differences there? The program starts running but input, int, input, and str are all highlighted red.

Comment: It executes, gets to the point where it says "what is your name: ", I type tim, and it says "...NameError: name 'tim' is not defined. Should I start a new thread for this problem?

Comment: It says it's in line 1

Comment: As I suspected it's because I am on 3.6 and you're on 2.7

Answer (score 0):

your code has some mistakes

```
name = int(input("enter your name"))
age = int(input("enter your age"))
year = 2017 - age + 100
print(name +"will be 100 year old in the year + year)
```

- here ypur mistake is here name is just a string and you tried to add string and integer @ print(name + "will be 100 years old in the year " + year)
  thats why you got error404